# Copy content from textarea to input and trim characters

Tags: jquery

First time here :)

I have a textarea and an input and I would like that, when something is typed into the texarea, it copies it to the input onkeypress. But the input must be limited to 10 characters. Then I would like to add 5 numbers to the end of the value of the input

EG:
Textarea content: "Hello world, how are you?"
Input content: "Hello worl12345"

I have tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bxHQ5/)  and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4kS65/523/)
but on the second one I think its really messed up code and requires some "cleaning". Besides, it lacks the function of adding 5 numbers at the end.

Comment: Welcome! next time, please include all the relevant data in your question, don't just link to some other site. Stack Overflow isn't a link proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to get the text area's value example:

```
var str = document.getElementById("text").value;
                          //id of text area needs to be set to "text"
```

then you could use the substring function to cut the string off after 10 characters

```
var finishedString = str.substring(0,10);
```

then if you wanted to just add 12345 to the end.

```
finishedString = finishedString + "12345";
```

and then use getElemendById of the input area to set it to the finished string.
You could put this all in a function and then call it on key pressed.

Comment: so you would need to add id values for the textarea and inputarea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $('#elementId').val();       // returns the element value
var trimmed = $.trim(value);             // trim the value;
var subString = trimmed.substr(0, 10);   // return the first 10 chars.
$('#otherElemetId').val(subString);      // set the substring as the value.
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bxHQ5/72/)

Comment: @user1413862, no problem!, don't forget to accept an answer(it's being done with the "check" sign near each question) or write an answer yourself if none of the existing answers helped you.